# AmAngularGauge show labels for bands only

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is there a way to show the labels on [Gauge](https://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/u3fobpbu/1/) chart only for bands' `endValue`? I saw the `labelFrequency` and `valueInterval` properties, but it's not helping.

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug but for me your fiddle is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to pass a function into the `labelFunction` property. Using this with `labelFrequency` and `valueInterval`, it is possible to achieve what you want ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/swp9j6g6/)) :

```
"valueInterval": 10,
"labelFrequency": 1,
"labelFunction" : function(value){
    if (value == 90 || value == 130 || value == 220){
        return value;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
},
```

However, I see two slight problems with this solution :

First, it is not possible to control the number of ticks on the axis anymore. This might become ugly, if you can't set an high value for the `valueInterval`.

Second, depending on how you decide the value for the beginning and the end of the gauge, this solution might require more work, like computing the GCD of the ranges (for `valueInterval`).